# How do I get data from a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given this hash that comes though :params

```
"positions"=>{
    "1"=>{"x"=>"50", "y"=>"30"}, 
    "2"=>{"x"=>"22", "y"=>"53"}, 
    "3"=>{"x"=>"68", "y"=>"35"}
 }
```

How would I do this? (doesn't work, but attempting to show what I want to do)

```
params[:positions].each do |position|
  logger.info(position.x)
end
```

I know, painfully beginner stuff ...

I get a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'x' for ["1", {"x"=>"50", "y"=>"30"}]:Array)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
params[:positions].each do |index, coords|
  logger.info(coords['x'])
end
```

If you don't care about the indexes, you could also just use `params[:positions].values.each do |coords|` instead.

Comment: This is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
positions = {
  "1"=>{"x"=>"50", "y"=>"30"},
  "2"=>{"x"=>"22", "y"=>"53"},
  "3"=>{"x"=>"68", "y"=>"35"}
}

positions.each_value do |hash|
  logger.info(hash['x'])
end
```

The `each_value` method will pull out the hashes (e.g. `{"x"=>"50", "y"=>"30"}`). In these hashes, your keys are strings, so you need to look inside these hashes with stringed keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for position[x] instead of position.x.

Comment: Tried that earlier too, "Undefined local variable or method 'x' for #<controller>"

Comment: Actually, position['x'] is what you're looking for in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Enumerable#each with a Hash you need to capture two block variables (this "unwraps" the array of key/value into two distinct variables). Also, Ruby does not use dot-syntax for hashes (this is not Javascript).

```
 some_hash.each do | (key, value)
    puts value["x"]
 end
```

This saves you from assembling an array of values first (using Hash#values).