# Ruby on Rails hash not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash that I want to extract the values from, but when I try its empty.

When I display the variable with the hash this is what shows.

```
{"raspado"=>{"id"=>28520497, "name"=>"Raspado", "profileIconId"=>508, "summonerLevel"=>30, "revisionDate"=>1394570420000}}
```

When I debug the variable with the hash this is what I get.

```
---
raspado:
  id: 28520497
  name: Raspado
  profileIconId: 508
  summonerLevel: 30
  revisionDate: 1394570420000
```

When I try to access a key via

```
debug @data[:id]
```

I get

```
--- 
...
```

what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is the key in the hash which is the value of key `raspado` of `@data`.

You should do:

```
debug @data['raspado']['id']
```

Comment: so simple... I'm new to ruby/rails so I'm having a hard time with the whole symbol thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple keys like '`raspado` in the hash', then you could get the values with the code below:

```
@data.each do |index, values|
  debug (values['x'])
end
```

ref: [How do I get data from a hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324432/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-hash)